# Convert app from iPhone 5 to iPhone 4 device

Tags: ios

How to make ios app compatible with iphone4 devices (i.e 3.5 inch), which is already built in iphone 5 (4.0 inch screen) without creating different xib?

Answer (score 2):

Use Autolayout to allow your app to correctly resize to the correct screen size. 
Raywenderlich.com has [a good tutorial to get you started](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2), and the Cocoa [Auto Layout Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/Introduction.html) is excellent, although it is written primarily for Mac apps.